# Trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on an older PC

Tags: boot, grub2, text

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an old Dell Studio XPS 7100. I created a bootable USB via Rufus, and when it loads, the text is all screwy.

I've read that I need to set the quiet splash to nomodeset, but with the garbled text, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Also, sometimes, when I select "Try and install" I get a black and white zigzag pattern and then it reboots.

Grub:

[image]

Comment: Try the "safe graphics" otpion. No need for `nomodeset`. Then, when installing, don't forget to check the option to install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc.

Comment: you mean the W'wnvw (Safg graphics) option? :P I'll give it a shot

Comment: @ChanganAuto That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After using the Safe Graphics option in GRUB I was able to boot into Ubuntu, however, I was still having issues. Turns out the graphic card was bad.
Replaced it and it worked like a charm.